# Cisco ACE Loadbalancer - Heavy Downloads Configuration

Tags: cisco, load-balancing

My hoster offers Cisco ACE loadbalancers in 30Mbit capacity steps. I am producing a lot of outgoing bandwidth in the order of gbit/s. I've read on a few online resources that there is a configuration that will make the server behind the loadbalancer communicate with the client requesting a download directly so the loadbalancer will only handle the actual GET Request but not the response. However I've failed to find this in the official documentation.

Does Cisco ACE support this? Do you have any keywords for me regarding the name of this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Linux world, this is called "direct server return" and with Cisco, it seems like they call it "Asymmetric Server Normalization" instead.

Check out some docs from Cisco here: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/interfaces_modules/services_modules/ace/v3.00_A2/configuration/slb/guide/rsfarms.html#wp1027634

Here is someone else who has attempted setting it up, which might be useful for your config: http://snippets101.blogspot.com/2008/08/asymmetric-server-normalization-on.html